# How to make `less` understand codepage?

Tags: character-encoding, less

```
LC_ALL=ru_RU.CP1251 less ~/t/show_discounts.js
```

shows nonsense characters instead of showing this CP1251 file as it should be viewed.

How to make `less` work well with specified encoding?

Debian Linux, Gnome Terminal with the system configured as as `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `less` as

```
LC_ALL=ru_RU.CP1251 less file
```

provided that `ru_RU.CP1251` locale exists on your system (see if `LC_ALL=ru_RU.CP1251 locale charmap` returns CP1252) tells `less` that you are in that locale, which means that the `file` is encoded in that charset **and** that the terminal uses that charset.

If the terminal emulator was started in a locale where the charset is UTF-8, it will expect characters coded in UTF-8 so won't know what to do with those CP1251 encoded characters that `less` is throwing at it.

You'd need to also start the terminal emulator in that locale, or you could use `luit` to do the translation (provided the terminal's charset is UTF-8).

Or you could use `iconv` to convert the file into the terminal's locale charset:

```
iconv -f CP1251 < file | less
```